# Null distribution of Rank tests

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I need to compute the distribution of a test statistic in C. The test statistic is based on ranks. So rather than generating observations and rank them I think I can use natural numbers and there all possible distinct combinations for my computation. So i have written a code in C. But it is not displaying the expected output, just some symbols I suppose. When I ran it in an online compiler it displayed a Segmentation fault. Please help me rectify the errors. Any suggestions will be appreciated. The following is the code that I have written.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
  int i1,i2,i3,j1,j2,j3,i,k,p,m1,n1,combo1,combo2,combo3;
  int fcombo1=0, fcombo2=0, fcombo3=0;
  m1=3;
  n1=3;
  p=1;
  int factorial(int n,int r);
  for(i1=1;i1<=6;i1++)
    for(i2=i1+1;i2<=6;i2++)
      for(i3=i2+1;i3<=6;i3++)
        for(j1=1;j1<=6;j1++)
          if(j1!=i1&&j1!=i2&&j1!=i3)
            for(j2=1;j2<=6;j2++)
              if(j2!=i1&&j2!=i2&&j2!=i3&&j2>j1)
                for(j3=1;j3<=6;j3++)
                  if(j3!=i1&&j3!=i2&&j3!=i3&&j3>j2)
                  {
                    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
                      for(k=0;k<=1;k++)
                      {
                        if(i==1)
                        {
                          combo1=factorial(i-1,1)*factorial(m1-1,p)*factorial(i1-i,p-k)*factorial(n1-i1+i,p+k+1);
                          fcombo1=fcombo1+combo1;
                        }
                        else if(i==2)
                        {
                          combo2=factorial(i-1,p)*factorial(m1-1,p)*factorial(i2-i,p-
                              k)*factorial(n1-i2+i,p+k+1);
                          fcombo2=fcombo2+combo2;
                        }
                        else if(i==3)
                        {
                          combo3=factorial(i-1,p)*factorial(m1-1,p)*factorial(i3-i,p-
                              k)*factorial(n1-i3+i,p+k+1);
                          fcombo3=fcombo3+combo3;
                        }
                        printf("%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d\n",i1,i2,i3,j1,j2,j3,
                            fcombo1,fcombo2,fcombo3);
                      }
                  }
  getch();
}

int factorial(int n,int r)
{
  if(n<r)
    return(0);
  else if(n==r)
    return(1);
  else if(r==1)
    return(n);
  else
    return(factorial(n-1,r)+factorial(n-1,r-1));
}
```

Output:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  0  0  0                                                                                                                                                     
1  2  3  4  5  6  0  0  0                                                                                                                                                     
1  2  3  4  5  6  0  0  0                                                                                                                                                     
1  2  3  4  5  6  0  2  0                                                                                                                                                     
1  2  3  4  5  6  0  2  0                                                                                                                                                     
1  2  3  4  5  6  0  2  4                                                                                                                                                     
1  2  4  3  5  6  0  2  4                                                                                                                                                     
1  2  4  3  5  6  0  2  4                                                                                                                                                     
1  2  4  3  5  6  0  2  4                                                                                                                                                     
1  2  4  3  5  6  0  4  4                                                                                                                                                     
1  2  4  3  5  6  0  4  8                                                                                                                                                     
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Your code is very hard to read...Please indent it properly...

Comment: Is that okay sir.?

Comment: No, you made it worse. :(

Comment: I am new to coding. So no idea how it should be written. Sorry.

Comment: The problem is you have 10 levels of nested for loops, which is a sign of not correctly designed program.

Comment: What is the solution? @fluter.

Comment: @ShashankShindhe What exactly is the desired output.

Comment: First, re think your logic, design an algorithm and try to break it down in smaller functions.

Comment: @rishikesh, the desired output is all possible distinct combinations of 6 numbers. then compute that multiplication of combinations.

Comment: @sourav there are no other ways. I just wanted to know why i am getting a segmentation fault. I have not violated any formatting statements, i have not used any pointers and i have not violated any arrays as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the way you design the program uses 10 levels of `for` loops, it is usually a terrible idea to do that, think about how you can refactor it.

Second, for the specific problem, it lies in the `factorial` function, if `r` goes to less than `0`, e.g. for the case of `factorial(1, 0)`, the function will recurse infinitely, because none of the termination condition matches. As a result, the program aborted by segfault because of stack overflow in the function. So depending on how you need to calculate, add a terminate condition in the function, for example:

```
int factorial(int n,int r)
{
    if(n<r)
      return(0);
    else if(n==r)
      return(1);
    else if(r<=1)
      return(n);
    else
      return(factorial(n-1,r)+factorial(n-1,r-1));
}

or

if (r <= 0) abort(); // this should never happen
```

Comment: Thank you@ flutter. as far as i have tried it there are no other ways of generating the natural numbers. Because there is condition on median of the total array. I need to work with that. Thanks a LOT FOR SUGGESTION.

Comment: @ShashankShindhe Ok, did the change fix the crash problem?

Comment: @ShashankShindhe that's right, you were asking why your program crashes. if the output is wrong, update your question what the expected output is.

Comment: I have done the same thing in excel. is it okay to send you that.

Answer (score 0):

> I just wanted to know why i am getting a segmentation fault....

I guess the reason is because of Stack Overflow. You are calling a recursive function `factorial` within a 8 levels of nesting. so this will be in the millions of calls.

Each time you call a function, some memory is allocated in the stack. Over millions of nested calls, the stack will overflow and cause a segmentation fault

Comment: is there a way to overcome this overflow.